# Google Patents search information

Tags: google-patents, google

I'm trying to do a project that requires the following data points from Google Patents:

1. The number of searches Google Patents has per day for the past ~10 years.
2. A list of searches on Google Patents has per day

I know that this data may be hard to get, but if anyone could direct me to any resources, that would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic. I very much doubt you'll get any useful answers. Why not just ask Google?

Comment: That's a good idea, but I'm not sure if they have good customer service for developers. Will try tho